# Count number of issues in each status after closing sprint

Tags: mdx

I want to count the number of issues in each state of jira board using EazyBi.
When I used "Issue History" it displayed the number of issues for each transition status correctly. However when I close the sprint, Issue History doesnot display any thing.
How can I see the report whenever I want for any sprint?

I tried to define new calculated member as below but it doesnot work:

```
Count(
 Filter(
  DescendantsSet([Issue].CurrentHierarchyMember,[Issue].[Issue]),
  [Measures].[Transitions to status]>0
  OR
  [Measures].[Issues history]>0 )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To view the Sprint Report in Jira, you need to:

1. Navigate to your desired board.
2. Click Reports, then select Sprint Report.
3. Select the relevant sprint from the sprint drop-down.
4. Click on "View in Issue Navigator" button (next to the header highlighting your present Sprint Number).
5. Apply the required filters like Project, Type, Status, Assignee, Sprint.¹

The Sprint Report shows the list of issues in each sprint.